# Why it is not saving values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have made an app, in which all of the radio button state is saved in local storage. All of the radio buttons have a values, but once I send the saved radio button values, I receive only 0, instead of the radio button values. But if i press at least one radio button, all of the values are normal. I have written a scrip if a radio button is checked, then an element will receive a value. That script works fine. So I came up to the conclusion, that my jQuery code isn't working properly.
Here is the jquery code, that save the radio button state.

```
$(function()
{    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + $(this).attr('id')) );

        if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
    });
}); $(window).bind('unload', function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {        localStorage.setItem(
            'radio_' + $(this).attr('id'), JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked})
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: could you share some HTML? or perhaps a fiddle?

Comment: You should do a console.log(localStorage) to see what is being saved to local storage

Comment: if state variable is not Boolean the condition will always fail, ( I am assuming storing is successful). just do if (state != null).

Comment: changed to (if (state != null) still the same. And console.log is showing only that if the radio button is checked or not

Comment: Ok, fixed it myself. I do apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

(I just saw you fixed it, but I'll still post this suggestion because it simplifies your code.)

Since you're dealing with radio buttons, I would just store the selected value. No need to explicitly loop over all buttons.

```
$(function()
{    
    var value = localStorage.getItem('selected_radio');
    $('input[type=radio][value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', true);

    $(window).bind('unload', function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem('selected_radio', $('input[type=radio]:checked').first().val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, even though I fixed it by not editing the jQuery code, still appreciate the answer